# Why is there 'n' in 'Kien Adamo volas iri'

Tags: grammar, accusative

I saw a sentence

> Kien Adamo volas iri?

Here I guess the 'n' in the 'Kien' makes 'to where' rather than 'where'.

Is it the same 'n' as in the objective of a verb, like "Mi manĝas pomon."?

If there is no n like 'Kie Adamo volas iri?', does it make different meaning or is it syntactically incorrect?

Comment: Kien? Al la butiko. Kie? En la parko.

Answer (score 5):

La finaĵo `-n` havas [plurajn rolojn](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/n/index.html). Tiu de `kien` ne estas tiu de `pomon`.

- Kien Adamo volas iri?

Tio demandas pri la direkto kaj `iri` povas signifi *Moviĝi direkte al iu aŭ io* ([PIV](https://vortaro.net/#iri_kd)).

- Kie Adamo volas iri?

Tio demandas pri la ejo kaj `iri` signifas *Moviĝi per la tiucelaj membroj, piedoj,...* ([PIV](https://vortaro.net/#iri_kd)). Iel kvazaŭ temus pri la ago marŝi.

La plej ofta signifo de `iri` estas `iri ien`, do la dua frazo aspektas iomete strange, sed ĝi bonas, se vi ne konsideras la agon `iri` alcela. Jen [ekzemplo](https://tekstaro.com/t?nomo=la-revizoro&id=am653#am653).

Answer (score 2):

> I saw a sentence
>
> > Kien Adamo volas iri?
>
> Here I guess the 'n' in the 'Kien' makes 'to where' rather than
> 'where'.

Don't let the English language confuse you. "where" has (at least) to meanings in English, which have to be distinguished by context:

- location ("At what place?")
- destination ("To what place?"), sometimes expressed as "where to" (almost never "to where"), but often just also as "where".

> Is it the same 'n' as in the objective of a verb, like "Mi manĝas
> pomon."?

That depends on what you consider "the same". It's the **same letter** (lower case N). It's there due to **accusative case** in both sentences. But the **reasons for using accusative a different**:

- In "Kien Adamo volas iri?" it's an accusative marking a location ("Kie") as a destination (of the movement "iri" itself of of its direction.)
- In "Mi manĝas pomon.", the accusative marks "pomo" as the direct object of the action "manĝi".

> If there is no n like 'Kie Adamo volas iri?', does it make different
> meaning or is it syntactically incorrect?

It'd be syntactically and grammatically perfectly correct, but indeed have a different meaning: It'd be a question about where (at what location) the movement "iri" takes place, rather than about its direction or destination.

Examples for location:

- Kie Adamo volas iri? (At what place does Adamo want to go?)
- Li volas iri en la strato. (He wants to go on the road / street. That's where the going takes place, not what its destination is.)
- Kie Sofia marŝas? (Where (at what place) is Sofia walking?)
- Ŝi marŝas en la montaro. (She walks in the mountains. (Not through tunnels, probably, but in a mountain range area, e.g. in the Alps.))

Examples for destination:

- Kie**n** Adamo volas iri? (Where(-to) does Adamo want to go?)
- Li volas iri **al** Torino. (He wants to go to Turin. "al" is already a preposition of destination/direction rather than of location, so no accusative here.)
- Kie**n** Sofia marŝas? (Where(-to) is Sofia walking?)
- Ŝi marŝas sur monto-pinto**n**. (She walks towards (or onto) a mountain top.)